# Javascript - post button not disabled - character count not working

Tags: javascript, button, count, character

This code is not giving me a disabled post button when I haven't inserted at least 1 character, and the character count is not functioning. I have checked index.html, to see that the js file is linked properly. I am using safari, have tried on chrome as well.

app.js file:

```
var main = function() {
$('.btn').click(function() {
    var post = $('.status-box').val();
    $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
    $('.status-box').val('');
    $('.counter').text(140);
    $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
});
$('.status-box').keyup(function() {
    var postLength = $(this).val().length;
    var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
    $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

    if(charactersLeft < 0) {
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else if(charactersLeft === 140) {
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else {
        $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
$('.btn').addClass('disabled');
};



$(document).ready(main);
```

html.index file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-   content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea class="form-control status-box" rows="2" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="button-group pull-right">
    <p class="counter">140</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Post</a>
  </div>

  <ul class="posts">
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Css file:

```
html,
body {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
color: #404040;
background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
width: 520px;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.button-group {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.counter {
display: inline;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.posts {
clear: both;
list-style: none;
padding-left: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.posts li {
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
word-wrap: break-word;
min-height: 42px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your html too? or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Do you get any errors reported in the browser console?

Comment: `keyup` is not a good event to use for this sort of thing. On modern browsers, `input` is best; on older browsers, you need a combination of things, primarily `change`, `keypress` (with a setTimeout delay), and the non-standard `paste`..

Comment: i think that the last else is removing the class disabled. remove the ligne : else {
        $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
    }

Comment: @IlyasMimouni: Not if either of the earlier conditions is true

Comment: Thanks for the answer, T.J. Crowder. But the issue I am running into now is that that that the "Send" button does not activate when adding characters...

Comment: I don't get any errors, the only issue I am experiencing is a non functioning post key and character count.

Comment: And whatever I write in the box is not published below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyup` is not a good event to use for this sort of thing. On modern browsers, `input` is best; on older browsers, you need a combination of things, primarily `change`, `keypress` and `keyup` (with a setTimeout delay, since the field isn't updated yet when they happen), and the non-standard `paste`..

For example (see comments):

```js
var main = function() {
    function enableDisableButtons(field) {
        var postLength = field.val().length;
        var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
        $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);

        // Note we can readily combine the two conditions and use toggleClass
        var disabled = charactersLeft < 0 || charactersLeft === 140;
        $('.btn').toggleClass('disabled', disabled);
        return disabled;
    }
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        // Proactively check when the button is clicked, in case all else failed
        if (enableDisableButtons($('.status-box'))) {
            return;
        }
        var post = $('.status-box').val();
        $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
        $('.status-box').val('');
        $('.counter').text(140);
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    });
    $('.status-box')
        .on("input change paste", function() {
            // Field is already updated when these happen
            enableDisableButtons($(this));
        })
        .on("keypress keyup", function() {
            // Field not be updated until just *after* these happen, so wait a tick
            setTimeout(enableDisableButtons.bind(null, $(this)), 0);
        });
    $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
.disabled {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="status-box"></textarea>
<input class="btn" type="button" value="Send">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Why use a `disabled` class rather than the button's intrinsic `disabled` feature?

Comment: This is my original html: